# jquery mobile grid view and list view on the same page

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile, gridview

New to jQuery Mobile. I have a list of stock that I want to be able to change the view of on the same page. So I have my list, then I want to be able to have two buttons at the top of the page:

- List view (default)
- Grid view

Then I can change the view of stock depending on which button I click. I have a working example:

Here's [an example URL](http://themeforest.net/item/bolt-jquery-mobile-website/full_screen_preview/2959847) view preview and click on 'Portfolio'

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by simpliest way. Just add list view and grid view in your site and `toggle` them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#Container ul { list-style: none; alignment-adjust:central; }
#Container .list li { //your list specs }
#Container .grid li { //your grid specs }​
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="content" id="Container">
    <ul data-role="listview" class="list">
        <li>list1</li>
        <li>list2</li>
        <li>list3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul data-role="listview" class="grid">
        <li>grid1</li>
        <li>grid2</li>
        <li>grid3</li>
        <li>grid4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```